# Efficient storage fetching for ListView.builder, GridView.builder

Tags: flutter, listview, fetch-api

In order to fetch data from the API with the builder function of `ListView.builder` or `GridView.builder` you have to create a list of Widgets that is being filled when you scroll.

The actual reason for using the Builder function is, to deal with large Lists so that only widgets are being rendered/build when needed:

```
List<Widget> _mediaList = [];
  int currentPage = 0;
  int? lastPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchNewMedia();
  }

  _handleScrollEvent(ScrollNotification scroll) {
    if (scroll.metrics.pixels / scroll.metrics.maxScrollExtent > 0.33) {
      if (currentPage != lastPage) {
        _fetchNewMedia();
      }
    }
  }

  _fetchNewMedia() async {
    lastPage = currentPage;

    setState(() {
      _mediaList.add(
        Text("Some Widget"),
      );
      currentPage++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification scroll) {
        _handleScrollEvent(scroll);
        return false;
      },
      child: GridView.builder(
          controller: widget.scrollCtr,
          itemCount: _mediaList.length,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _mediaList[index];
          }),
    );
  }
```

The problem that I see is, that if you have an endless list (like a Post feed), that the list would store every Data source and the list would eventually jam up the RAM.

I would imagine that you either have to clear the list after scrolling for a long time or you would need to only store String-IDs and load the data according to them.

Is that concern appropriate or does the builder also optimize the storage in that case?

Answer (score 0):

> You should store String-IDs and build the list items using `FutureBuilder()`. Because although `ListView.builder()` renders only those items which are visible on the device screen but in case of post feed the post   data may consume so much storage which can cause efficiency problem.

Comment: Could you make an example? And how would you call the String-ID list, because if I only store String-IDs the Builder would need to fetch/rebuild the Data every time I move(also the one i see)?